# Firebase Android setDisplayName not saving

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to save a user's displayname using Firebase's setDisplayName function, but it is not saving. My code is the following:

```
UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName(userNameEditText.getText().toString())
                .setPhotoUri(croppedUri)
                .build();
        if(user != null) {
            user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "User profile updated.");
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

Note: This user is authenticated via Firebase email password

PS: userNameEditText.getText().toString() gives me the proper string, but when I try user.getDisplayName() it returns "". Also, it says the task is successful, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Can you tell us where are you using this code? Is it in the click of a button? ... And where do you call `getDisplayName()`?

Comment: Hi Rosario, It appears that I am now able to get the displayName. Very strange, I did not change anything since I made this post except restart my computer.

Comment: Maybe you have Instant Run enabled and you were running some previous code... Anyway it's a good thing it works now! :)

Comment: Yes it is, thank you :)